# Strings dont retain \ in c# when read by database

Tags: c#, database, string, .net-core

In my C# program i can configure RegEx patterns in a database. If i read this RegEx Patterns from the database it doesnt match the strings which should be matched by the regex patterns. If i write the RegEx pattern hard-coded in the c# code it matches.

I think the problem is the backslash which is read differently during database read. Here is my small code:

```
string regExString = @listOfRegexen[counter].RegEx;
int regExStringLength = regExString.Length;
string regExWorking= @"(?=.*?^\[\)>@)(?=.*?[@]P(?<MATNR>.{7,7}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]1T(?<Lot>.{0,30}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]K(?<OrderNo>.{0,15}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]V(?<SupplierNo>.{0,5}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]2P(?<RevisionNo>.{0,4}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]20P(?<SICKSupplierNo>.{0,8}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]Q(?<Quantity>.{0,8}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]Z(?<SerialNo>.{0,10}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]10D(?<DatCode>.{0,4}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]4L(?<Origin>.{0,2}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]14D(?<ExpiryDate>.{0,8}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]1T(?<Charge>.{0,25}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]6D(?<DeliveryDate>.{0,11}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]12V(?<Manufacturer>.{0,30}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]1P(?<ManufacturerNo>.{0,25}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]T(?<PackagingUnitID>(\d{7}\@\d{5}\-\d{8})?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]30P(?<Humidsensitivity>.{0,2}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]1V(?<Supplier>.{0,30}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]E(?<RoHs>.{0,2}))(?=.*?@)";
int regExWorkingLength= regExWorking.Length;


int comparison = String.Compare(regExString, regExFunktionierenderString, comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The value of regExStringLength is 829 and the value of regExWorkingLength is 827. When i hover during debugging over the variables it seems for me completly identical.

The value which is read by the database is saved in regExString and is saved in the database like the following:

```
(?=.*?^\[\)>@)(?=.*?[@]P(?<MATNR>.{7,7}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]1T(?<Lot>.{0,30}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]K(?<OrderNo>.{0,15}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]V(?<SupplierNo>.{0,5}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]2P(?<RevisionNo>.{0,4}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]20P(?<SICKSupplierNo>.{0,8}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]Q(?<Quantity>.{0,8}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]Z(?<SerialNo>.{0,10}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]10D(?<DatCode>.{0,4}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]4L(?<Origin>.{0,2}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]14D(?<ExpiryDate>.{0,8}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]1T(?<Charge>.{0,25}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]6D(?<DeliveryDate>.{0,11}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]12V(?<Manufacturer>.{0,30}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]1P(?<ManufacturerNo>.{0,25}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]T(?<PackagingUnitID>(\d{7}\@\d{5}\-\d{8})?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]30P(?<Humidsensitivity>.{0,2}?)(?:@))(?=.*?@)(?=.*?[@]1V(?<Supplier>.{0,30}?)(?:@))(?=.*?[@]E(?<RoHs>.{0,2}))(?=.*?@)
```

I also printed both strings with Console.WriteLine here is the result:

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: 1) when you compare regExStringLength with regExWorkingLength (programmatically, not visually), you get "same" even when their length is different?
2) "how to solve" - one approach can be divide-&-conquer: try reducing regex string to isolate problematic parts

also, wud u like to explictly mention in ur question what value is there in database and what value is being fetched in ur code when u print it?

Comment: @gawkface i think its obvious that the character "Backslash" makes problems but i can not figure it out how i can fix it. Every regex which doesnt contain normal backslashes works.

Comment: so is ur question about (a) how to create a regex with backslash for ur string or (b) how to read string with backslash from db into c# code intact? also, backslash being the "obvious" problem is ur hunch or hv u pintpointed? wud be nice to know which backslash is causing the problem to then explain why

Comment: @gawkface The regex is correctly created and is saved in the database. During the read-process from the database the "encoding" or something like that doesnt work identically like when i write the same regex hard coded in the c# code like shown. So my question is, how could i get the same string which contains backslashes from database like when i write it hard coded in the c# code. Like i said, the string length is not equal which means some encoding or so is making some differences.

Comment: Wild guess: two chars difference in length, may that be a CR/LF at the end? Try and compare the first (say) 10 chars of each, or check whether the longer one "StartsWith" the smaller one. Or do a for-loop, comparing chars at each index - they you *know* where the problem is

Comment: How are you storing that string in the database? If you use parameters (as you should) then there should be no interpretation of "special characters" like a backslash. Note also that the debugger may show an interpretation of what is actually in memory for a string (converts it to code-ready representation).

Comment: Can you compare both strings this way: `String.Join("", ?.Select(c => ((ushort)c).ToString("X4")));`  where ? is either `regExWorking` or `regExString`?

Comment: You have *seven* backslashes in that regex: 2 at the start `(?=.*?^\[\)>@)` and 5 near the end `(?<PackagingUnitID>(\d{7}\@\d{5}\-\d{8})?)(?:@))`, I don't know how that will translate to a 2-char difference

Answer (score 0):

some approaches you can experiment with:

1. `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';` (reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

   - remember to "take backup of ur sql modes" when experimenting
   - restart ur application to reinitiate sql connection with correct modes I guess
2. in your database value, insert double \ in ur string wherever there is single \

one or the other (or combination of both) worked for me eventually when I was trying on my mocked environment : p (need to now reset it back to how it was lol)

Comment: start with the 2nd approach I would say

Comment: i assumed u were using mysql, perhaps u can add to ur post what db u r using too